# How to update TextView from AsynkTask?

Tags: android

This is my code: (Some random text to complete question osdifhgsoid hgodfhgo hsdhoigifdshgnvfa oidvojd nobndisfn vbjobsf).

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            Listen();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            textIn.setText("shit! " + x.toString());
        }
        long i = 10;
        return i;
    }
}
```

(Some random text again to complete question(stupid system) dpfgojd ipgsdigjsidoignsdog

```
public void Listen(){
    int count = 0;
    TextView msg = MyActivity.msg;
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket client;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(9797);
        Log.d("My log", "server started");
        Log.d("My log", "waiting for connnections");
        while (started) {
            try{
                msg.setText("waiting for connection"); <=== here crashing
                client = server.accept();
                count++;
                Log.d("My Log", "Connected");
                Log.d("My Log", "aha" + count);
                int i = 0;
                String data = null;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
                while (is.available() == 0) {
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    }catch (Exception cc){}
                }
                is.read(bytes, 0, is.available());
                os.write("hala".getBytes());
                client.close();
            }catch (Exception cc)
            {
                cc.toString();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception el) {
        el.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(Some random text to complete question). Please help

Comment: I'm not really sure why your AsyncTask expects a Long as return value if you don't plan on using it. A better approach would be to have Void as return value. I'll update my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

change it via the onPostExecute method!

Comment: I have added onPostExecute inside DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask and pasted msg.setText(action), which doesn't work.
How to call this method?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an AsyncTask is to do a long running task in a separate thread and then communicate the result back to the UI thread via onPostExecute().

Also, I'm not sure why you use Long as your return value since you do not seem to be using it. A much better solution would be to have Void as return value and save the exception and use that as an indicator if anything went wrong:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    private Exception exception = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            Listen();
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
            exception = x;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(exception != null) {
            textIn.setText("shit! " + exception.toString());
        }
        else {
            // long running task was completed successfully
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're wrong. Have a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you are trying to set the TextView inside the `doInBackground`() method, and this is not allowed.

So there is a solution if you want to set the TextView inside the `doInBackground`() method, do the UI updating operations inside the [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

**Otherwise**, suggestion is to do all the UI display/update related operations inside the `onPostExecute`() method instead of doInBackground() method of your AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea would be to return a String in `doInBackground()`, say `exceptionCatched`. You can set it to `Exception` title in `catch()` block and then in `onPostExecuted()` just check `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(exceptionCatched)) textIn.setText(exceptionCatched);` That's it!

Comment: An even better approach would be to save the Exception in a member variable (since he is subclassing AsyncTask) and retrieve it in the onPostExecute() method

Comment: Not sure if it's better or worse but it is a good approach as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask  extends AsyncTask<Void,    Void,Long>{

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
        publishProgress(progress);
        //calculate progress and value from your  downloading logic 
    try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return (long) 0;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //dis method run deafult on UI thread , so every time u publish ur onProgressUpdate will be called and update ur text here 
    }


     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result==0){
            //error occured
        }
    }
```

// in case of exception return the result as long value to promt to onPostExceute()

Comment: Why would you want to use 0 as an indicator of an error and null as an indicator that the task was successful?

Comment: it is just upto your usage i just simply provided the right implementation for his problem

Comment: if somehow no exception occur and the user want to see the progress may be in textview then he has to publish it .

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29). You can't update the UI from any other thread than the UI thread.

Comment: The purpose of an AsyncTask is to not have to worry about runOnUiThread and the like. Override onPostExecute() and do you update there.

Comment: Ah, good point there, I'm still a beginner so I wasn't aware `AsyncTask` could be used like that. Thanks for pointing it out ;)